# не пойму в чем проблема

Tags: javascript

Объявить переменные «first» и «second» назначить им значения 10 и 20, а затем переменную «result», а ей сумму значений переменных «first» и «second».

```js
var first, second, result;
first = "10";
second = "20";
char result = " 10 + 20";
```

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: опять учебное задание

Comment: Создайте сначала переменные, далее массив (пустой), потом добавляйте и т. д. Что ж тут такого..., в книжках это есть... В чем именно у вас проблема? В каком моменте затруднения?

Comment: С чем возникли сложности при выполнении задания?

Comment: В js нет типа `char` (.

Comment: а как тогда обьявить переменную?

Comment: ``"10"`` не равно 10 и ``"20"`` не равно 20.

Comment: Вы ее уже объявили: `var ... result;`

Comment: вы строки слаживаете

Comment: @Эникейщик, Это смотря как сравнивать :-)

Comment: точнее просто строка где вы их слаживаете

Comment: спасибо, разобралась. все оказалось проще.

Answer (score 0):

вот просто:

```
let first = '10';
let second = '20';
let result = (first + second);
```

Comment: Вы сейчас пытайтесь ответить на вопрос который задан 4 года назад, учебный и автор которого не посещал сайт 4 года. И ответ ваш тоже "не очень".

Comment: @Paul, запусти свой пример и посмотри что у тебя получилось в итоге...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]